# Invalid access to resource - Speech To Text API

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am getting the following error when I try to open a websocket.

> Invalid access to resource -
>   /speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&watson-token=
>
> User access not Authorized.
>
> Gateway Error Code : ERCD04-NOAUTHHDR-PLTFRMREQ
>
> Unable to communicate with Watson.
>
> Request URL :
>   /speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?model=en-US_BroadbandModel&watson-token=
>
> Error Id : stream-dp01-47767984
>
> Date-Time : 2016-03-26T16:05:04-04:00

I have no idea what this error means. I am using this client code in Golang to open the websocket.

```
// Simplified code to get token
baseURL, _ := url.Parse("https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token")
params := url.Values{}
params.Add("url", "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api")
baseURL.RawQuery = params.Encode()

req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, baseURL.String(), nil)
req.SetBasicAuth(IBMUsername, IBMPassword)
resp, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
token, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

// Simplified code to open websocket
baseURL, _ := url.Parse("wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize")
params := url.Values{}
params.Add("watson-token", token)
params.Add("model", "en-US_BroadbandModel")
baseURL.RawQuery = params.Encode()

ws, _ := websocket.Dial(baseURL.String(), "", "http://localhost:8000")
```

Comment: Hello, are you passing the authentication credentials in the REST call to get the auth token? You need to use Basic Auth to get a token.

please let me know

Comment: @DanielBolanos I am. You can see the part of my code above where I use basic auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is experiencing some issues right now; the team is aware and working on it. Sorry for the trouble, please try again in a little while.

Comment: How can I know when it is fixed?

Comment: It should be working now. I'm not sure if there's a public status page, but there probably should be. I'll ask around.

Comment: Try appending the watson-token directly to the URL, sometimes url encoding the tokens can cause issues.

Comment: Alternatively, you could skip the token and just add a basic auth header to the websocket. Not sure if the built-in websocket lib supports custom headers, but Gorilla's does: https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/client.go#L37

Comment: I added the basic auth header to the websocket request and it worked.